# the fragment after swipe to next fragment and get back display nothing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

i have a `view pager` that contains some `fragment` and add another fragment to this view pager.
in this new fragment i have a `list` that contains some data from `db`.
when i start my app its working good . `swipe` to this fragment show the list but when i swipe to next fragment and get back its an empty list :/
i tried to set the adapter for the list in both `onViewCreated` and `onActivityCreated` , but doesnt change anything.

Comment: is the fragment you swipe to is the next fragment just after this fragment? or there is some other fragment between them?

Comment: i have 3 fragment and create some fragment from the third one , in this case i mean the second one ! i test it now , its ok when i swipe it with next and before fragment but when i go to last fragment (for example pos 4) and get back its empty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because fragmenting in Android only stores the state of the next fragment and previous fragment of the fragment you start with, and destroys the others in order to keep the efficiency of the system, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611709/1638739). as the adapter build to destroy the fragments which are two steps away from the fragment you are in now.

Comment: but my first fragment is like the second one! why this not happening for it ?

Comment: your first two fragments will be stored, then when you go to the third fragment, the first one will destroyed and the second will remain as it's, and in the forth the second will destroyed also but the third will remain. and by saying destroyed, that means the layout will be recreated when you come back so that any run-time changes you made to the fragment will disappear(like creating a `List`), and that means if you have a fragment with fixed `Views` you won't notice any change. any for the fragments with dynamic Views you just have to recreate it when coming back.

Comment: i understand what you say ! the question is why my first fragment list get not empty ? its happening only for my second one ! is there anyway to recover list data ?

Comment: i have list in both of first and second fragment

Comment: it's about your way to handle the fragmenting, I don't know why the first one still there, may be you some how reinitialize it and create it again when going to the first fragment, but all you have to do to overcome the list problem of the second fragment or any other fragment, to recreate it, or to store it in a static reference and then recreate it using these values when coming back to fragment, I think you know about `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` methods of each fragment. Just use onViewCreated() to recreate the list again using the `view` attribute.

Comment: the problem was about my `list adapter` ! create a new instance in `onViewCreated` make my problem resolved ! but thanks for your useful info :)

Comment: @y.feizi you are welcome:) ,and happy that your problem solved